# Using UTF-8 encoding, CSV file with special properties/foreign characters not preserved when imported into MySQL (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

My table needs to support pretty much all characters (Japanese, Danish, Russian, etc.)

However, while saving the 2-columned table as CSV from Excel with UTF-8 encoding, then importing it with phpMyAdmin with UTF-8 encoding selected, a lot of the original characters go missing (the ones with special properties such as umlauts, accents, etc.) Also, anything following problematic characters is removed entirely. I haven't the slightest idea what is causing this problem.

**EDIT: For those that come upon the same issue, I'd suggest opening your CSV file in Notepad++ and going to "Encoding > Convert to UTF-8" (not "Encode in UTF-8") first. Then import it. It will surely work.**

Comment: Can you look at the CSV file in a Unicode-capable editor and check if it has indeed been saved correctly? Does the font you're using support Unicode?

Comment: Neither do we. You'll have to do some basic troubleshooting yourself.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - I've opened the file using Notepad++, which tells me the file was NOT UTF-8, and was instead ANSI. The first time I did this I selected "Encoding > Encode in UTF-8" then saved it. Still wouldn't import correctly. However, there is another option in Notepad++ under "Encoding" called "Convert to UTF-8". That's what confused me. It appears that my table has now imported correctly using the second option. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: @MarcDelisle - version 4.0.9 using XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer here:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003837

Bascially save as a unicode text file from excel,
then replace all tabs with commas in code friendly text editor,
re-save as utf8
change file from .txt to .csv

exporting directly from excel to .csv causes problems with Japanese, this is why I went searching for help...